# Laravel application will not route properly

Tags: laravel, routes, controller

I am trying to create a first application using TCPDF and Laravel 8. I have an initial page which has a listing of users from a MySQL table and two buttons (Download PDF and View PDF)

There are three routes setup in my web.php file:

```
Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index');
Route::get('download', 'App\Http\Controllers\PDFTestController@savePDF')->name('download');
Route::get('viewpdf', 'App\Http\Controllers\PDFTestController@openPDF')->name('viewpdf');
```

I have tried creating the buttons and their actions several different ways but the result is always the same:

```
// The download button
<button type="button" onclick="window.location='{{ route("download")}}'" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Download PDF</button>

// The view button
<a href="viewpdf" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Open PDF</a>
```

The route for the home page correctly calls App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index and the expected page is displayed.

However, when I try the download page all I get is a 404 "The requested URL was not found on this server." and the URL it is trying is .../LaravelPDF/public/download

Clicking the View button results in a 404 as well and the URL is /LaravelPDF/public/viewpdf

I put some DD() calls in the various functions and it does not appear that they are ever being called.  Instead Laravel is trying to open a view named download or viewpdf.

I even tried creating a download.blade.php file but that does not open either.

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `php artisan route:clear`?

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately it did not make a difference.

Answer (score -1):

Just Run your terminal

> php artisan route:clear

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately it did not make a difference.

Comment: you can use      <button type="button" onclick="window.location='{{ url("download") }}'">Button</button>

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but this also results in a 404 cannot find /LaravelPDF/public/download

Clearly Route::get('download', 'App\Http\Controllers\PDFTestController@savePDF')->name('download'); is never executing which I do not understand since Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index'); does work.